# Parse <img src> tag in JSON - iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have an iOS app which downloads a JSON feed. I have managed to parse everything just fine apart from one element left, which is the images.

The JSON feed I am downloading is from a PHP script online which converts certain RSS feeds to JSON. Thus why there are `HTML` image tags in one of the elements of the JSON feed which contains the images.

I am using the following code to access things like titles, dates, link URLS, etc... and it works great:

```
NSArray *titles = [[[[data_dict objectForKey:@"rss"] valueForKey:@"channel"] valueForKey:@"item"] valueForKey:@"title"];
```

As you can see from my code above, the titles are stored in the JSON tag called "title". Very easy to parse. The images are stored in a tag called "description".

How this tag also contains text as well as image URLS. So how can I parse the `<img src>` tags from it?

Here is one of the JSON description tags:

[image]

How can I go about parse the image links in an array?

Thanks for your time, Dan

Comment: You could use NSAttributedString and read the HTML text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code -

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = @"";

    NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourHTMLSourceCodeString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourHTMLSourceCodeString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSString *img = [yourHTMLSourceCodeString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];

                         NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:img];

                         if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
                         }


                     }];
```

**Update** 
Same thing can be done using below regex change -

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"]((http|https)://.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
```

Comment: Ok this is pretty awesome solution! Just one question, sometime in these feeds other random image appear in the description tag like images which end with ".img" or image links that don't even have an image extension at the end of the link. How can I tell those links apart? I only want to show images that are actually part of the website feed, not random images like "rssbutton.img"?

Comment: You can do using regex change also  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"]((http|https)://.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"

Comment: No that didn't work. I actually ended up adding another if statement in your code ```if (([img containsString:@".jpg"]) || ([img containsString:@".png"]) || ([img containsString:@".jpeg"])) {...}``` to decide whether or not to use the image. Thanks for your help :)